# Mac OSX $python3 test_imagenet.py --image images/dog_beagle.png ImportError: No module named 'cv2'

Tags: python, macos, computer-vision, keras

I am using the tutorial found [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/08/10/imagenet-classification-with-python-and-keras/)

The error I get on the command line and for the Pycharm IDE is that `cv2` can't be installed. Is this a problem because I am using a Macbook or can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

If the error is saying "no module named cv2", you need to install OpenCV. You can do this with homebrew using `brew install opencv`

For detailed instructions, take a look at: http://www.mobileway.net/2015/02/14/install-opencv-for-python-on-mac-os-x/

---

**MORE INFO:**

With opencv installed with brew, you just need to know the package location. Go to `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/` to find out your version number. I just installed with brew and have 2.4.13.

Once you know that, navigate to your Python directory with `cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`

You can then run each of these to link them up to Python:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.13/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py cv.py
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.13/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so cv2.so
```

(replace the 2.4.13 with the version number you have)

Hope that helps. I don't think it will be any easier with Windows, though.

Comment: Did you also do the part under "Python setup"?

Comment: $python3 and $python both give errors, "no module named cv2" I might have to try to use windows to sort this out.

Comment: That error simply means that the python environment doesn't know about cv2. It probably won't be any easier on a Windows computer really. You just need to link the cv2 package files, which installed with brew, to your site-packages directory. I'll update my answer with more details.